# Aligning depth image to RGB image

Tags: c#, kinect

I've been trying to align the depth stream to my RGB stream from my Kinect for quite some time. I've read several articles about it but I must be missing some key point because I cannot get it to work...

Here is an image of what I have managed to do, I've circled some easy to spot misalignments
[image: Kinect Depth misalignment]

I've been trying to get this down into as small code as possible, but its still a good chunk of code so please bear with me, the code snippet below is what the Kinect SDK calls everytime there is a depth and RGB frame ready.

As you can see I've been experimenting with

```
ColorImagePoint colorpoint = _Sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthPointToColorPoint(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30, depthpoint, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
```

I would prefer to use CoordinateMapper.MapDepthFrameToColorFrame (as this should be able to solve the problem) but I can't get it to work.. I am probably not doing it correctly though..

I am using Microsofts Kinect SDK 1.6

```
private void EventAllFramesReady(Object Sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Color color;

    Bitmap image = null;
    Bitmap depth = null;

    using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
    {
        using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
        {
            // color 
            image = new Bitmap(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height);
            byte[] colorPixels = new byte[colorFrame.PixelDataLength];
            colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(colorPixels);

            //lock bitmap, and work with BitmapData (way faster than SetPixel())
            BitmapData imageBitmapData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
                                                ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                                                image.PixelFormat);
            IntPtr IptrImage = imageBitmapData.Scan0;
            byte[] PixelsImage = new byte[image.Width * image.Height * 4];


            // depth
            depth = new Bitmap(depthFrame.Width, depthFrame.Height);
            DepthImagePixel[] depthData = new DepthImagePixel[depthFrame.PixelDataLength];
            depthFrame.CopyDepthImagePixelDataTo(depthData);

            //lock bitmap, and work with BitmapData (way faster than SetPixel())
            BitmapData depthBitmapData = depth.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, depth.Width, depth.Height),
                                                ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                                                depth.PixelFormat);
            IntPtr IptrDepth = depthBitmapData.Scan0;
            byte[] PixelsDepth = new byte[depth.Width * depth.Height * 4];


            DepthImagePoint depthpoint = new DepthImagePoint();

            for (int x = 1; x < colorFrame.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 1; y < colorFrame.Height; y++)
                {
                    int i = ((y * image.Width) + x) * 4;

                    short depthdistanceRAW = (depthData[x + y * depth.Width]).Depth;

                    // convert distance value into a color
                    color = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;
                    if (depthdistanceRAW > 0 && depthdistanceRAW <= 4000)
                    {
                        int depthdistance = (int)((depthdistanceRAW / 4090f) * 255f);
                        color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb((int)(depthdistance / 2f), depthdistance, (int)(depthdistance * 0.7f));
                    }

                    depthpoint.X = x;
                    depthpoint.Y = y;
                    depthpoint.Depth = depthdistanceRAW;

                    ColorImagePoint colorpoint = _Sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthPointToColorPoint(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30, depthpoint, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

                    //if (colorpoint.X > 0 && colorpoint.X <= 640 && colorpoint.Y > 0 && colorpoint.Y <= 480)
                    //{
                    int adjustedposition = ((colorpoint.Y * image.Width) + colorpoint.X) * 4;
                    //if (adjustedposition < depthData.Length)
                    //{
                    PixelsDepth[i] = color.B;
                    PixelsDepth[i + 1] = color.G;
                    PixelsDepth[i + 2] = color.R;
                    PixelsDepth[i + 3] = DepthTransparency;
                    //}
                    //}

                    PixelsImage[i] = colorPixels[i];
                    PixelsImage[i + 1] = colorPixels[i + 1];
                    PixelsImage[i + 2] = colorPixels[i + 2];
                    PixelsImage[i + 3] = 255;
                }
            }

            Marshal.Copy(PixelsImage, 0, IptrImage, PixelsImage.Length);
            image.UnlockBits(imageBitmapData);

            Marshal.Copy(PixelsDepth, 0, IptrDepth, PixelsDepth.Length);
            depth.UnlockBits(depthBitmapData);
        }
    }

    _kf.UpdateImage(image); // update the RGB picture in the form
    _kf.UpdateDepth(depth); // update the Depth picture in the form
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer to a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682863/kinect-1-8-colorframe-and-depthframe-not-coordinated).

The [Coordinate Mapping Basics-WPF C# Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973086.aspx) shows how to use this method. You can find some significant parts of the code in the following:

```
// Intermediate storage for the depth data received from the sensor
private DepthImagePixel[] depthPixels;
// Intermediate storage for the color data received from the camera
private byte[] colorPixels;
// Intermediate storage for the depth to color mapping
private ColorImagePoint[] colorCoordinates;
// Inverse scaling factor between color and depth
private int colorToDepthDivisor;
// Format we will use for the depth stream
private const DepthImageFormat DepthFormat = DepthImageFormat.Resolution320x240Fps30;
// Format we will use for the color stream
private const ColorImageFormat ColorFormat = ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30;

//...

// Initialization
this.colorCoordinates = new ColorImagePoint[this.sensor.DepthStream.FramePixelDataLength];
this.depthWidth = this.sensor.DepthStream.FrameWidth;
this.depthHeight = this.sensor.DepthStream.FrameHeight;
int colorWidth = this.sensor.ColorStream.FrameWidth;
int colorHeight = this.sensor.ColorStream.FrameHeight;
this.colorToDepthDivisor = colorWidth / this.depthWidth;
this.sensor.AllFramesReady += this.SensorAllFramesReady;

//...

private void SensorAllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
    // in the middle of shutting down, so nothing to do
    if (null == this.sensor)
    {
        return;
    }

    bool depthReceived = false;
    bool colorReceived = false;

    using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
    {
        if (null != depthFrame)
        {
            // Copy the pixel data from the image to a temporary array
            depthFrame.CopyDepthImagePixelDataTo(this.depthPixels);

            depthReceived = true;
        }
    }

    using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
    {
        if (null != colorFrame)
        {
            // Copy the pixel data from the image to a temporary array
            colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.colorPixels);

            colorReceived = true;
        }
    }

    if (true == depthReceived)
    {
        this.sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthFrameToColorFrame(
            DepthFormat,
            this.depthPixels,
            ColorFormat,
            this.colorCoordinates);

        // ...

        int depthIndex = x + (y * this.depthWidth);
        DepthImagePixel depthPixel = this.depthPixels[depthIndex];

        // scale color coordinates to depth resolution
        int X = colorImagePoint.X / this.colorToDepthDivisor;
        int Y = colorImagePoint.Y / this.colorToDepthDivisor;

        // depthPixel is the depth for the (X,Y) pixel in the color frame
    }
}
```